# Calculate order of a graph from size of graph and size if its complementary.

Tags: graph-theory

Given the order of a graph (without loops) n, which size is 56. And its complementary graph which size is 80.

How to find out the value of n?

Comment: $$ q_{E}+q_{E^c}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=136\implies n=17$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$q_{E}+q_{E^c}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=136\implies n=17$$

Comment: Sorry byt the very same answer was posted by Behrouz before you. I'm accepting his answer he if replies.

Comment: @VíctorRomero Note that I posted it as "community wiki", so I don't get any reputation/points from this post. See [this meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments) regarding questions which get answered in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: the graph and its complement together make up the complete graph $K_n$.  What can you say about the sum of their sizes in terms of $n$?